# How to create functions of arbitrary number of variables?

Tags: programming, variable-definitions, list-manipulation

In the following code what would be the simplest way to generalize it to say some $N_f$ number of $z$ instead of just $z_1$ and $z_2$?

```
$Assumptions = {1 > y > 0, 1 > z1 > 0, 1 > z2 > 0}; 
Nmax = 40; 
LnMT1 = -Sum[Log[1 - (1/(1 + x^n)) (x^(n/2) (y^(n/2) + z1^n + z2^n) + 
   x^(n/2) (y^(-n/2) + z1^(-n) + z2^(-n)))], {n, 1, Nmax}]; 
LnMT2 = Sum[(1/n) (Sum[x^(k*(n/2))*Subscript[f, k][y, z1, z2, n], 
   {k, 1, Nmax}]/(1 - x^(2*n))), {n, 1, Nmax}]; 

For[i = 1, i <= Nmax, i++, 
  temp[y_, z1_, z2_] = Simplify[Solve[SeriesCoefficient[LnMT1 - LnMT2, {x, 0, i/2}] == 0, 
     Subscript[f, i][y, z1, z2, 1]][[1, 1, 2]]]; 
  Print["coefficient of ", x^{i/2}, " = ", Expand[Simplify[temp[y, z1, z2]]]]; 
  Subscript[f, i][y_, z1_, z2_, n_] = temp[y^n, z1^n, z2^n]
]
```

- I guess the places where there is a sum over the nth powers of `z1` and `z2`, they canbe replaced by  `Sum[z[j]^n, {j, 1, Nf}]`  but the problem is with the "functions" "temp" and $f_i$ which will need to handle $N_f$ number of variables.  I tried defining expressions like, 
  `g[Table[z[i], {i, 1, Nf}]] = Sum[z[j]^2, {j, 1, Nf}]` but I couldn't do anything with them. And I anyway don't know how to define a function of $N_f$ variables. (..one can't pass values to the above $g$...and in the above code one would want to even functionally update $f_i$ as in the last line of the loop.
- Also in the "Print" line when I am printing out the evaluated expression for temp often I want to print the value of temp with one or more of its variables (y and z) being set to 1. If the above code can be generalized to arbitrary number of z then how would this setting to one be done then?

Note: in all of it I am assuming that at the start there will be a new line declaring the value of $N_f$ to be used as is being done now for `Nmax`

Comment: You code cannot be executed by copy&paste. Can you please recheck it and reduce it to the *smallest possible* part which still shows your behavior?

Comment: I again converted the code into "InputForm" and pasted it. I have checked that it works.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a function, you use `Blank` to match exactly one expression. Therefore `z1_` stands for *match one parameter*. As you might have seen, we have `BlankSequence` (`__`) and `BlankNullSequence` (`___`) too. The former matches *one or more expressions*, while the latter matches *zero, one or more expressions*. Therefore, you can define a function like

```
f[z__] := {z}

f[a]
f[1,{123},b,c]
f[a,b,c]
(*
  {a}
  {1,{123},b,c}
  {a,b,c}
*)
```

to match as many parameters as you like. You can of course do something with the parameters

```
g[z__] := Sum[Sqrt[elm], {elm, {z}}]
g[a,b,c,d]
(* Sqrt[a]+Sqrt[b]+Sqrt[c]+Sqrt[d] *)
```

You may now say *but I cannot access single `z1` for instance. First, yes you can

```
h[y__] := With[{z = {y}}, z[[1]] + z[[5]]]
h[a, b, c, d, e]
(* a + e *)
```

but secondly, what would be the use of this? When I access `z[[5]]`, the function is not general anymore, because I expect always at least 5 parameters.

Comment: Didn't understand how your answer corresponds to my question. Now I can define 2 variable functions like $f[z1_,z2_] := $ and I can manually keep increasing it by adding extra zs through the code by hand. What I want to do is to define $f$ such that it is a function of $Nf$ zs and be able to set the value of Nf at the beginning.

Comment: @user6818 Can you come [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)?

Comment: yes I am logged into chat

Comment: what is `elm` in this case?

Comment: @anhnha Why don't you try it out? `Sum[Sqrt[elm], {elm, {1, t, "blub"}}]`

Comment: @halirutan I did try the code and wrote another one replacing `Sqrt` with another function. I knew what it does but it doesn't tell how it does that or how it work like that.

Comment: @halirutan I just realized that the part inside `Sum` can be like a `Table` format.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `Repeated`?

A function with five arguments:

```
  ClearAll[h];
  h[z : Repeated[_, {5}]] := Plus @@ {z}
  {h[1], h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], h[a, b, c, d, e], h[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, a]}
  (* {h[1],15,a+b+c+d+e,h[1,2,3,4,5,6,a]} *)
```

another example with five arguments:

```
   ClearAll[h2];
   h2[z : Repeated[_, {5}]] := {z}[[2]] + {z}[[3]]
   {h2[1], h2[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], h2[a, b, c, d, e], h2[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, a]}
   (* {h2[1],5,b+c,h2[1,2,3,4,5,6,a]}  *)
```

Another alternative is to use `Condition`

```
  ClearAll[h3, h4, h5];
  mm = 5;
  h3[z___ /; Length[{z}] == mm] := Max[z]
  h4[z___] /; Length[{z}] == mm := Max[z]
  h5[z___] := Max[z] /; Length[{z}] == mm
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking just at the question in the title without going through the rest of the code, my simple answer would be to define your functions to take **exactly one argument** `zList` at all times, where `zList` is a `List` (as the name says). This list can have any number of arguments, and the function can run through them in a way that adapts to `Length[ zList ]` (preferably by using constructs like `Map` that operate on the whole list at once).

Comment: The issue is with being able to treat each of these zs as variables to which values can be passed. You can see how "temp" needs to be defined in the first line of the loop and how $f_i$ is updated by temp in the last line of the loop. How would one achieve these even if I make these functions of tables of z? Also in the "Print" line I often want to print the value of temp with all of its arguments set to a value 1. How does one achieve that?