# Function with different set of arguments

Tags: function-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create functions of arbitrary number of variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16233/how-to-create-functions-of-arbitrary-number-of-variables)

i want to use a Function `f[]` with different set of arguments.
example: `f[{x,y,z}]` as well as `f[{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...,{xn,yn,zn}]`. How do i write its definition to accept Both type of calls.

Comment: This could be considered a duplicate of [How to create functions of arbitrary number of variables?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16233/245)

Answer (score 7):

The pattern matching in Mathematica gives you a powerful way to define recursive functions.

For example if you'd like to write a function which takes a Mathematica function definition and generates C-Code from it:

```
<< SymbolicC`
ClearAll[toSymbolicC]
SetAttributes[toSymbolicC, {HoldAll}]
toSymbolicC[x_List] := toSymbolicC /@ x
toSymbolicC[(op : (Plus | Times))[args___]] := 
           COperator[op, toSymbolicC[{args}]]
toSymbolicC[(op : (Cos | Sin))[x_]] := 
           CStandardMathOperator[op, toSymbolicC[x]]
toSymbolicC[x_] := x
```

I know this should be more elaborated but for the sake brevity I just defined functions for lists, two commutative operators, Cos and his imaginary friend ;).

You'd use it in that way:

```
toSymbolicC[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]
```

which yields:

```
COperator[Plus, {CStandardMathOperator[Cos, x], CStandardMathOperator[Sin, x]}]
```

to convert this into a regular C-Expression you'd use (of course you could've done this in postfix form)

```
ToCCodeString[%]
```

Hope this gave an idea about the power of pattern matching, especially in symbolic programming languages like Mathematica.

[Patterns in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html)

Answer (score 3):

You simply write them:

```
f[{x_,y_,z_}]:= definition1
f[{x_,y_,z_},{x1_,y1_,z1_},{x2_,y2_,z2_}]:= definition2
```

Of if you want to match this pattern one or more times you can use the `Repeated` pattern operator `..`, and bind the sequence of matches to a single variable `p`:

```
f[p:({_,_,_}..)] := definition3
```

Mathematica will use the most specific pattern that matches a call.

Comment: @jVincentMy definitions of f[] depend on number of Arguments, How do i know how many arguments have been passed ?

Comment: @user4972 In the above you know for certain that definition 1 has one passed, and definition 2 has three passed. In the last definition, the matched `p` be equal to `Sequence[{x,y,z},{x1,y1,z1},...,{xN,yN,zN}]`, so you can find the length using `Length[{p}]`. Note that `{}` is needed due to the way `Sequence` works.

Comment: So instead Of 1st 2 definitions, i can directly use last one and use Length[{p}] for number of times to execute my operations right ?

Comment: @user4972 Yes, the first two examples where to highlight how you would go about if you knew exactly what numbers it should work for.

Comment: okay.And how do i identify each set of arguments and work on them ? Can i find it like p[[i]] till length[{p}] ?

Comment: @user4972 Because of the way `Sequence` works, `p` cannot be used directly as a list, you have to use for instance `{p}[[i]]`.