# Write Power in CForm[] as multiplication instead

Tags: formatting, code-generation, c++

Is there a simple way to make Mathematica write `CForm[p^2]` **not** as `Power[p,2]` but rather as `p*p` and so on for other much more complicated expressions?

Comment: I think the best way is to try to make use of the SymbolicC package.  [See here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46844/12).  I am always struggling when trying to extend `CForm` to behave better.

Comment: One more suggestion: if you are dealing with polynomials, you can consider putting them into `HornerForm` for more efficient evaluation.  And a shameless plug: if you evaluate many integer powers in C++ (not in C), you may be interested in [my blog post on the topic](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/fast-computation-of-powers.html).  In fact you might want to generate `power<n>(x)` with a small extension to SymbolicC.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the default [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) handling of [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) as follows:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power[a_,n_Integer?Positive], CForm] := Distribute[
    ConstantArray[Hold[a],n],
    Hold, List, HoldForm, Times
]
Protect[Power];
```

Example:

```
CForm[p^3]

(* p*p*p *)
```

The only downside is that I don't know how to control parenthesization, so that:

```
CForm[x^2 y^3]

(* x*x*(y*y*y) *)
```

unnecessarily parenthesizes `y*y*y`.

Comment: Hello, I got weird results if the power is -1. Is there a way to fix it? I.e. `CForm[a*p^-1]` works fine but `CForm[p^-1]` does not.

Comment: @VsevolodA. see update

Comment: Thanks. Though now it's not working for negative powers (it previously worked fine): the only problem was with the -1 power expression when there are no constants around like `p^-1`.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Do you have an example where it doesn't work for negative powers? It works for me.

Comment: Sure, `CForm[1*p^-2]`

Answer (score 3):

If the symbol you are using is known in advance, you can use[`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) and associate an [`UpValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValue.html) with that symbol inside the [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html)function:

```
p /: Power[p, 2] := HoldForm[p*p]
```

Then

```
CForm[p^2]
```

> `p*p`

Comment: This works BUT seems to break things -- Solve stopped working right, and I got strange results in some calculations.  If you do this, I'd suggest doing it right before you use CForm, and then right afterwards undo it by doing p /: Power[p,2] = .