# Can I define a function for vectors of arbitrary dimension?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Is it possible to do analytic calculations with *Mathematica*?
For example, I want to compute:

$$\partial \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n G_{j} \prod_{k=1}^{j-1} (1 - G_{k})}{\partial G_l}=-\prod_{k\neq l} (G_k-1)$$
Is it possible to define such analytic functions for an arbitrary parameter $n$?

Right now, I do it by hand by defining a function like this

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] = a + b (1 - a) + c (1 - a) (1 - b) + d (1 - a) (1 - b) (1 - c)
```

but I want to do it generally for an $n$-vector, not a 4-vector

Comment: Related: [(21281)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21281/121)

Comment: Going by the title, this is a duplicate of [How to create functions of arbitrary number of variables?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16233/245)

Comment: $n$ is the upper limit of the sum over j? $l$ is also not defined.

Answer (score 9):

Define a function (with thanks to Mr. Wizard for the more compact form)

```
g[a_] := Sum[a[[i]] Product[(1 - a[[j]]), {j, i - 1}], {i, Length[a]}]
```

In this function, `a` is a list like `{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}` and so `a[1]` corresponds to your variable `a`, `a[2]` corresponds to your `b`, etc.

To use this, observe that

```
g[{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}]
```

gives

```
a[1] + (1 - a[1]) a[2] + (1 - a[1]) (1 - a[2]) a[3] + (1 - a[1]) (1 - a[2]) (1 - a[3]) a[4]
```

which is the equivalent of your `f`. More generally, let

```
aVec = Array[a, 7];
g[aVec]
```

and you get the 7-term case,

Comment: I like your solution, i think is way cleaner than the ones that referenced from the duplicate answers. But can I compute derivatives from a vector coordinate?

Comment: They're just symbols. Here's an example: `D[a[1]^2 + a[2]^3 + a[1] a[2], a[1]]`. It gives `2 a[1] + a[2]` as you would expect.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another option that I like:

```
f = #.FoldList[# (1 - #2) &, 1, Most@#] &;

f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> a + (1 - a) b + (1 - a) (1 - b) c + (1 - a) (1 - b) (1 - c) d
> ```

If you need input in the multi-argument syntax you may write:

```
g = {##}.FoldList[# (1 - #2) &, 1, Most@{##}] &;

g[a, b, c, d]
```

> ```
> a + (1 - a) b + (1 - a) (1 - b) c + (1 - a) (1 - b) (1 - c) d
> ```